# Create List or Array of Specified Data Points

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

Simple question, may have already been answered.  Looking to make a list or an array between two specified values.  I want to also be able to control how many values are in the list.

For instance, lets say I want a list of values between 0 and pi, and I want the list to be 10 numbers long it would read something like

```
[0, 0.349, 0.698, 1.05, 1.40, 1.74, 2.09, 2.44, 2.79, 3.14]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I can of course easily build my own function to do this.  I was looking for something like range(), or np.arange().  An already built in function or something from a library

Comment: Without importing a package: `[lower_bound + i*((upper_bound-lower_bound)/(n-1)) for i in range(n)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, [`numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) does the trick:

```
import numpy as np

res = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 10)

array([ 0.        ,  0.34906585,  0.6981317 ,  1.04719755,  1.3962634 ,
        1.74532925,  2.0943951 ,  2.44346095,  2.7925268 ,  3.14159265])
```

For a list, you can use `res.tolist()`.

Comment: linespace!  I knew I had heard of it before.  Thank you.  This is exactly what I am looking for.